# Pandas - Merging multiple dataframes on multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have multiple dataframes that need to be merged on multiple fields.

I've seen posts on merging multiple dataframes, but not on multiple fields.

I have to merge 30 dataframes so trying to come up with a better solution than individually merging them.

First I use a function to rename the fields, but the final dataframe (`reduce_output`) only has 2 reports merged and are duplicated multiple times. Plus, all the columns have the same name except for one.

```py
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd


def merge_helper(df1, df2):
    name = df2["Report Name"][0]
    print(f"Rpt Name of DF2{name}")
    name1 = df1["Report Name"][0]
    print(f"Rpt Name of DF1{name1}")
    out = pd.merge(
        left=df1,
        right=df2,
        on=(
            "Date",
            "Entity ID",
            "Field",
            "Price Type",
            "Return Type",
            "Linkage",
            "Benchmark #",
        ),
        how="outer",
        suffixes=("", "_remove"),
    )
    try:
        out.rename(columns={"Data_Value": f"Data_Value{name1}"}, inplace=True)
    except:
        print("no_such_column")
    out.rename(columns={"Data_Value_remove": f"Data_Value{name}"}, inplace=True)
    out.drop(
        labels=[i for i in out.columns if "remove" in i],
        axis=1,
        inplace=True,
    )
    print(out.columns)
    return out


reduce_output = reduce(
    function=lambda x, y: merge_helper(df1=x, df2=y),
    sequence=[reports[0], reports[1], reports[2], reports[3], reports[4]],
)
```

Comment: you need to break up your function.. first, cleanse the data (rename all columns of all dataframes to the same col name). second, merge. when merging, why don't you use a `for` loop (`df = pd.merge(df, df_other)`, but instead a `lambda` function? Seems complicated if in fact you just want to do merge multiple `dfs`. Why `outer` merge? Please break down your problem, clarify where you see unexpected output. Does the renaming work? Does a single merge work? Do multiple merges (in a `for` loop) work? Is the output structure as expected, or do you need `pd.concat` rather than `pd.merge`?